# How can I effectively shield block with a tower shield?

Tags: shield, pathfinder-2e, defense

I am a champion with a shield ally and a [tower shield](https://2e.aonprd.com/Shields.aspx).  Shield ally adds +2 to my shield's hardness and 50% HP and BT. So a normal tower shield in my hands has a hardness of 7 and 30 HP.

I want to be able to do two things: use shield block to reduce damage for myself and allies, and use raise shield/take cover to provide AC and cover bonuses.

How can I keep shield block effective past my initial levels? There are some magic shields that increase HP and hardness, but I haven't seen one that is a tower shield. Are there any shields, class features, feats, or strategies that I can use to keep shield block with a tower shield effective?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly Tower shields do not have many options. [Everstand Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1087) can further raise your hardness. Unfortunately most special materials are disallowed for tower shields except for darkwood, the higher grades for them do raise the hardness and hp of your shield (in addition of freeing up some bulk.

Comment: Although dissatisfying, I searched for every usage of "shield" in Archives of Nethys today and found nothing else. Enjoy that green check mark.

Comment: It's probably worth noting the [Talisman](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=155) from my post on a related question can be applied to "effectively" have more hp on a Tower Shield. [Mending Lattice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=224). If it isn't PFS, I would be surprised if a GM refused to allow Sturdy or Reforging *Tower* Shields to be found/bought/crafted.